# How to do the same thing for many objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code and I want instead to repeat it over and over again 
to write it in short/better way,is it possible in JS?

```
    runCo.addContent(oTtlLo);
    runCo.addContent(oLblP);
    runCo.addContent(oAcFileP);
    runCo.addContent(oTvFiL);
    runCo.addContent(oTtlP);
```

and I've more then 10 lines more for that ....

Comment: better names is the only thing that can be said of this code unless there is an aggregate `addContent` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1. create an array holding the objects

```
var array = [ oTtlLo, oLblP, oAcFileP, oTvFiL, oTtlP ];
```

Step 2. loop through the array

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    runCo.addContent(array[i]);
}
```

Additionally, your variable names are very unclear. You could make them much more clear. I can't think of any reason why you want every variable name to start with `o`. Abbrevations such as `Lbl` (assumingly for `Label`) is unnecessary, just write `label` instead. And `P` (for `Player`? for `Pizza`?) doesn't say anything either.